# Java read file by command line, <(less than) symbol

Tags: java, cmd, terminal, command-line-arguments

I am trying to read the filename by the command line,

This is command that our professor wants us to type:

```
java MultiBinaryClient xxxxxx.edu 6001 < files.txt
```

I was trying to use `args[3]` to get the file name, but args only contains `"xxxxxx.edu"` and `"6001"`. why not `"<"` and `"files.txt"` in the `args[]`? Can anyone help me out?

BTW, I am using MAC terminal to test my code, I believe my professor uses win CMD, will it make differences?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Let's see what each fragment means. This is how we execute a Java class containing a `main` method:

```
java MultiBinaryClient
```

The only command-line arguments that are being passed to your program are these ones:

```
xxxxxx.edu 6001
```

And this snippet is *not* part of the expected arguments to the Java program:

```
< files.txt
```

It's just Unix shell syntax to specify that the contents of `files.txt` must be read into your program via the standard input.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old question, but I've had this problem recently. Here's what I've done to handle it:

Well, as the others said, the "<" redirects the file contents to stdin. If you want to use the file contents as program arguments, you can use xargs:

```
xargs -a FILE java JAVA_ARGS
```

or, more specifically:

```
xargs -a FILE java -cp CLASSPATH CLASS_WITH_MAIN_METHOD
```

Answer (score 0):

< is a redirection. The file will be streaming over stdin.

Answer (score -1):

You should escape the '<'

```
java MultiBinaryClient xxxxxx.edu 6001 \< files.txt
```